# How can I block a user from viewing certain files on a server in their browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xmlhttprequest

I have a ASP.Net MVC application that is generating xml files dynamically when the user requests (via http request). The only problem is that it will also write them into a file stored locally. So I really have two questions:

1. Is it possible to not write the file locally but still send the response with the file to the client only
2. Or can I block a user from typing in the file URL and viewing it on their browser such as example.com/test.xml

I have an authentication system in place to control access of certain views, but I don't know how to do this for something without a view

Current way of writing file and sending response:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public void SendXML()
{
    if(!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return;
    }

    string path = Server.MapPath("~/Temp/test.xml");

    using (Stream s = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(s, settings))
        {
            // Write Xml Document
        }
    }

    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    Response.TransmitFile(path);
}
```

Current Way of sending request:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        // Good
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://example.com/MyController/SendXML", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to not write the file locally but still send the
> response with the file to the client only

Yes. It is possible. Once you have the XML in a string. Instead of writing that XML to a file and sending, You can convert the `XML` string to a `byte array` and then to an `octet stream` and send it down from API. This will download the file for the end user and ofcouse you are not storing anything to filesystem

```
var xml = @"<root></root>";
byte[] xmlBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
var stream = new MemoryStream(xmlBytes); 
return File(stream, "application/octet-stream", "DownloadName.xml");
```

> Or can I block a user from typing in the file URL and viewing it on
> their browser such as example.com/test.xml

It depends, You can have multiple options. You can integrate an authentication mechanism like cookie authentication or token authentication like IdentityServer to facilitate protected endpoints. If you have protected endpoints you can restrict access to only specific users.

Comment: Does this method maintain the structure of the xml?

Comment: Yes it will. What ever the XML string will be there on the downloaded file. If you want indentation you need to have "\n" and "\t" on your XML string